# How safe is redirecting to another site?

Tags: web-application, url-redirection

Lets say I have a website at `https://example.com/test`. Whenever someone accesses this site, I want to just simply redirect them to `https://example.com/Test`.

Are there any possible vulnerabilities here? Or is this method safe since all I am doing is redirecting from one secured site to another?

Comment: Is it just one redirect from one site to another, or are you hinting at some sort of rule for how you redirect depending on upper and lower case?

Comment: You ask about "another site", but this generally looks like the same site.

Comment: You ask "another site", but give same-site examples. Can you clarify which you mean?

Comment: To expound on @chrylis and EthanKaminski's comments, the term "site" is generally used to refer to a domain, while "page" refers to a particular address. So `https://example.com/test` and `https://example.com/Test` are different webpages on the `https://example.com` site.

Comment: You may be interested in this method: [`history.replaceState(null, document.title, 'Test');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method)

Comment: @Acccumulation: While this might be nitpicky, I have the gut feeling it needs clarification: `https://example.com` is not a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), but a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (or more generally a URI, which is a superset of URLs and URNs). And I am not sure if one can say that "(web)site" is used to refer to the startpage, a.k.a. [homepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_page). Even further, whole websites (and arbitrary many of them) may be located on any URL, not just the one featuring nothing after the slash behind the domain.

Comment: @phresnel URLs are used to identify domains. I didn't say that "site" refers to the homepage; "https://example.com/test and https://example.com/Test are different webpages on the https://example.com site." clearly means that the site is not just the homepage but other pages as well.

Comment: @Accumulation: `URLs are used to identify domains`: This does not make more sense than "Cars identify license plates" or "Bicycles are mounted to brakes". A domain is just one possible part of a URL. In oversimplified form, a URL goes like this: `[scheme]://[domain]/[path]` 
 (for full definitions, see URLs provided earlier).

Answer (score 30):

`/test` and `/Test` are both hosted on example.com … so it's just a page redirect not a domain redirect … this is a non-issue.

People redirect like this all the time, for instance redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS is pretty much industry standard at this point.

Comment: The exception would be if a domain has been subdivided. E.g. user1 has control over `example.com/user1` and subdomains, user2 has control over `example.com/user2` and subdomains, etc. And theoretically, if the string "https://example.com/test" is generated dynamically, that could open an injection vulnerability.

Comment: maybe? but a redirect doesnt automatically grant you permission ... if I get redirected from /index.html to /superTopsecretKittys.html ... im still going to get a `401 Unauthorized`

Comment: Yes, but it raises phishing issues. If I can get do an injection attack that gets a website to redirect users to my website, then I be like "Whoops, there's an error, you need to re-enter your credentials".

Comment: thats a completely different issue ... if you inject something into someones website ... they have bigger problems then a simple redirect.

Comment: I wouldn't mention HTTP to HTTPS here. There *are* some weak spots in doing so that aren't relevant to the OP's description.

Comment: As an aside, redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS has a lot more considerations than a more "standard" redirect. You're potentially very vulnerable to SSL strip and if you're doing such a redirect, you almost certainly want to look into HSTS preload and the weaknesses of that method. Mind you, even with HSTS, you're potentially vulnerable to SSL strip with a look-a-like domain... :/

Answer (score 18):

Implemented correctly, there are no issues with this.

There are two things you should look out for (I assume that `test` is not static here, but user supplied, so you eg want to upper-case every path):

- Open Redirect: If your redirect is implemented incorrectly, it might be possible for an attacker to redirect outside of your domain, which could be used in phishing attacks
- CSRF: If your CSRF protection is only a simple referer check (which isn't recommended), and if you have state-changing GET requests (which also is not recommended), those may be possible to exploit, depending on your implementation of the redirect mechanism

Answer (score 9):

Redirecting users to different page or domain is a normal practice followed by many developers (even MNC's including FB, fb.com redirects to facebook.com). It's no harm if you try to redirect requests in a secure way.

You might want to check [OWASP Cheat Sheet for Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.md) (Also called Open Redirection). This document provides to secure ways to redirect URL in multiple programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

As far as `hostname` remains same and your user trust it. It should not be a problem.

This sort of redirection are common across internet and help to provide a better user experience.

> #### For instance:
>
> you have a resource at `https://testwebsite.com/Test` but due to some typo or 
>    developer's mistake it is written as `https://testwebsite.com/test`. The redirection will help user to see an appropriate file instead of seeing a `404 file not found` error or `Internal server error`.

Answer (score -4):

1. Redirect within the same domain - no risk. (because your domain is trusted)

   Example: `https://domain.com/login` redirect to `https://domain.com/dashboard`
2. Redirect to third party website is medium severity risk if you are leaking sensitive data like access_token, secret keys to the third party website.

   Example: `https://domain.com/redirect_to_fb` redirect user to `https://fb.com`
3. Attacker controlled redirect leads to:

   a. Phishing `https://domain.com/login?redirect_to=http://evil.com`

   b. Cross Site Scripting (XSS) issue: `https://domain.com/login?redirect_to=javascript:alert(document.cookie)`

   c. Leaking tokens Example: `https://domain.com/login?redirect_to=https://attackerdomain.com` Example: `https://r0rshark.github.io/2015/09/15/microsoft/`

   d. Content Security Policy bypass

   e. Referrer check bypass

   f. URL whitelist bypass

   g. Angular ng-include bypass

If an attacker is able to control the redirect then it's a serious issue.

Comment: Sadly the edit does not improve the answer.